# How to create AVD for lower api in android ADT bundle?

Tags: android, adt, android-virtual-device

I am using ADT bundle to create android apps. I am only able to create AVD with api level 19. I want to create AVD with lower api, say api 10 and test the app. I guess `system-images` of lower api has to be installed to created AVD with lower api. In SDK manager , however, I cannot find `system-images` except for api 19. I might have deleted them by mistakes earlier. How to bring them back or is there any way to create AVD with lower api ?

Comment: 1st download api level 10 in ur `sdk manager`..

Answer (score 1):

Just install SDK of the corresponding API and restart the eclipse in the ADT bundle. Now, you can see the updated dropdown in the `target` field.